# Python 3.4 - Error creating .exe with cx_freeze - Tkinter-docx-xlwt modules

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze, xlwt, python-docx

When creating an .exe file of a python script wich uses tkinter, docx and xlwt, I get this error when I try to run the created file.

[Screenshoot](http://prntscr.com/e37dao)

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
# replaces commandline arg 'build'
sys.argv.append("build")  
# change the filename to your program file --->
filename = "casdaf.py"
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = "Circle",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Nothing",
    executables = [Executable(filename, base=base)])
```

Yes, the script contains the `root.mainloop()` at the end.

I guess the problem comes from one of the libraries...

EDIT: Solved by using Pyinstaller